# How can I save inputted html data by user(using JS) in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, page-refresh, savechanges

I have my php app called CALENDAR. On load page the calendar is empty.

[image]

I have methods that after I click on the specific cell, the html code is inputted iside.

For example one of the method looks like this(whole calendar is a `<table>`):

```
    function shift3()
     {
        $('td').dblclick(function() {
            var clicked_cell = ($(this).attr('id'));
            $("#"+clicked_cell).html('<div id="shift3">9:00 <br> 17:00</div>')

        });

    }
```

Here is how the calendar looks like after some clicks:
[image]

The question is how I can save the file(calendar.php) that after I refresh the page those purple squares wont disappear ?

Comment: either 1) use ajax to send the data to server, and have php insert it into a database, or 2) use client side persistence like indexeddb. either way, so is for getting help with non-working code, it is not a free code writing service. try something yourself first. as is, this question is way too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very simple app. I would like to save changes to the file(calendar.php) and replace this file on the server that when I or someone else open the app my changes will be shown.

Comment: yeah, so what did you try so far? post some code. what kind of answer do you expect to get by posting? i've already told you to use ajax.. what else do you need to know?